# CSS background styles stop working after changing background with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a script to automatically change background image after a set of time on my site. Everything works fine but after changing to new background images, I have to add background styles in JavaScript again because background styles in my css file stop working right after that

Only `transition: 2s` still works so I have to add all the background styles in JavaScript again...

But adding background styles in JavaScript make the screen flicker every time background changes. So I'm looking for a solution if possible.

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body');
body.style.background = 'url("new_bg")';
body.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
body.style.backgroundSize = '100%';
body.style.backgroundAttachment = 'fixed';
```

```css
body {
  background: url("bg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it to make a [mcve]

Comment: The Javascript code has a mistake please make background url a string.

Comment: Be aware of specificity weight. JS will apply inline-style which has a higher specificity as css and will always overwrite them (unless `!imporant` is used).

Comment: You can get an image from lorem kitten

Comment: @tacoshy THIS IT! I can't believe it's so simple. Everything works after using !important. Thanks alot, this totally fixes my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening here is that you are resetting the entire background style everytime you call your script.

These two lines are different:

```css
.someClass {
    background-image: url('');
}
.someClass {
    background: url('');
}
```

The first example resets the background image only. The second one resets every property on the background because you are using the `background` shorthand.

If you just reset `background-image` in the javascript, it won't reset everything else.

Comment: Now i understand why it happens like that. Thanks for your help. I also found that using !important fixes my problem too but your answer explained it perfectly.